# Custom Script Extension not working on Red Hat 7.2

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I am unable to get Custom Script Extension working on Red Hat 7.2. I tried the latest extension and have the following in my ARM template -

`{
      "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNamePrefix'), parameters('startingNumeral')[copyindex()],'/',parameters('VMNamePrefix'), parameters('startingNumeral')[copyindex()],'-CUSTOMSCRIPT')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "location": "[parameters('region')]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersionVirtualMachines')]",
      "tags": {
        "ApmID": "[parameters('apmID')]",
        "ApplicationName": "[parameters('applicationName')]",
        "SharedService": "[parameters('sharedService')]",
        "PaaSOnly": "[parameters('paasOnly')]"
      },
      "copy": {
        "name": "customScriptLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmInstanceCount')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat(parameters('VMNamePrefix'), parameters('startingNumeral')[copyindex()])]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": [
            "[variables('customScriptUri')]"
          ]
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
          "commandToExecute": "[parameters('customScriptCommand')]"
        }
      }
    }`

The command to execute is `pwd` but after like 90 minutes, the extension gives up and I see the following in the `waagent.log` log file on Red Hat 7.2 -

`2018/09/10 13:30:49.361162 INFO [Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension-1.9.1] Target handler state: enabled
2018/09/10 13:30:49.390061 INFO [Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension-1.9.1] [Enable] current handler state is: notinstalled
2018/09/10 13:30:49.585331 INFO [Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension-1.9.1] Initialize extension directory
2018/09/10 13:30:49.615784 INFO [Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension-1.9.1] Update settings file: 0.settings
2018/09/10 13:30:49.644631 INFO [Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension-1.9.1] Install extension [install.cmd]
2018/09/10 13:30:50.678474 WARNING [Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension-1.9.1] [ExtensionError] Non-zero exit code: 127, install.cmd
2018/09/10 13:30:50.713928 INFO [Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension-1.9.1] Remove extension handler directory: /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension-1.9.1
2018/09/10 13:30:50.723392 INFO ExtHandler ProcessGoalState completed [incarnation 4; 1534 ms]`

I am not seeing any other logs as well. Any idea what could be going wrong? When I manually go and install the Custom Script extension from the portal, it works fine.

Thanks,
Pranav

Comment: Do you check if the agent is at work and see the [Tips and Tricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux#tips-and-tricks)?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT - Yea, that seems to work because I am getting the metrics and other stuff. What I don't understand is how come there is "install.cmd"?

Comment: What about the "commandToExecute" you set and your customscript?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT - The command to execute is set to `pwd` which should print the current working directory. But, isn't the CMD extension for Windows? I can provide other details like subscription & VM name as well if you say.

Comment: For example. You should set the command in "commandToExecute" to execute the customscript which you set in the "fileUris". See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/features-linux#azure-resource-manager-templates).

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT - I have tried that as well. But, from what I see, `commandToExecute` can execute any single command. And this is not only my subscription. Seeing this with a client as well.

Comment: I mean if you want to set extension with a custom script, you should set a command in "commandToExecute" to execute the script, not other commands.

Comment: Do you solve the problem?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT - I have narrowed down the issue to the extension not liking passing a SAS storage link and excluding "storageAccountKey" & "storageAccountName" parameters from the template. Earlier the extension was happy with the SAS link but now it is not...

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT - Any update on this?

Comment: I have no idea in current station. Coud you provide the whole template? I could test for you.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT - Do you want me to provide you the whole template here or is there any email address where I could pass it on?

Comment: You can put it in the github and give me the address.